# ActiveRecord models "losing" their find_by_* methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, resque

We have a relatively standard Ruby on Rails project, which has quite a few background jobs that run under Resque (with Redis as a backend.)

The issue is that very rarely -- perhaps once a month, maybe a little less -- we'll suddenly see floods of exceptions from Resque. The exceptions are all in the following vein:

```
undefined method `find_by_id` for User():Class
undefined method `find_by_name` for CustomerAccount():Class
undefined method `find_by_id` for Job():Class
```

It *appears* that suddenly, all ActiveRecord::Base models lose their `find_by_*` methods for the entire thread. Restarting the worker fixes the issue.

I know that generically, the answer must be "someone, somewhere -- probably in a gem -- is breaking method_missing somehow." Or perhaps, somehow the constants are getting reassigned to a different class. But before I begin a really thorough investigation, I wanted to check if anyone has run into this problem and solved it already.

This project is running Ruby 2.1.1p76, Rails 3.2.17, Resque 1.25.1.

Comment: I know these finders were deprecated in Rails 4.0 and there is a gem that gets them back (https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders), but you don't seem to be using anything like it...

Comment: Can you replace those methods with `where(...).first`? They're all going away anyway so you're going to have to replace them sooner or later. You could also patch `find_by(x)` (as `where(x).first`) into ActiveRecord and use that instead, `find_by` comes in with Rails4 so your code will be future-compatible, you'll just have to remember to kill your monkey patch when you upgrade.

Comment: @D-side rails 4.0 did not depreciate `find_by_xxx`. [See Here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record-deprecations). They did depreciate many of the dynamic finders but these are not on the list. Although this does seem to be a misconception that has spread to many developers.

Comment: @engineersmnky Got it. Regardless, this is Rails 3. So my first comment is overall useless. It might prevent some people wandering in that direction though.

Comment: `find_by_*` methods are implemented through `method_missing`/`respond_to?`. `respond_to?` checks if a column with a particular name exists. I guess, if your connection to the database fails at some point for some reason, you start getting these errors as the set of columns known to your application is empty. Can you check your logs for the traces of the failed/closed connections in workers?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the equivalent of "find\_all\_by\_id" in rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31867062/what-is-the-equivalent-of-find-all-by-id-in-rails-4)

Comment: @moonfly It turns out the issue was indeed db connection dropping; knowing the root cause, it was easy to add checks for this and reconnect.  If you want to turn your comment into an answer, I'm happy to award some ancient and much-delayed answer credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing the loop on this ancient question: it turns out moonfly's comment was indeed the issue, and in long-running workers, a dropped database connection would result in this (somewhat strange) error message.

Knowing the root cause, we were able to add a periodic conn refresh (to try and keep the connection alive when a worker was idle for too long), and also, to add a detection mechanism for when a db conn *was* dropped, and to reconnect. So, thanks much @moonfly, if you'd like to turn your comment into an answer I'm happy to award you much-delayed answer credit.